# Drupal, where is edit account tab in user profile

Tags: drupal-6

After login, my account page is display, but I can't find edit tab. I can see only registered profile values without editing option. :(

Could somebody tell me why?

Another issue I am getting is hook_validate problem.
I added to my custom module:

```
function advert_user_validate($node, &$form) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo var_dump($form);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

But it seems that this function is never invoke.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a theming issue. Switch to Garland and then see if the tab is there.  If it is, it is indeed a theming issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just append `/edit` to the url of the My Account page.
i.e., if the url of your My Account page is `example.org/user/3`, add `/edit` to it and access `example.org/user/3/edit`. In your case, replace the number `3` before `/edit` with your user_id.